# How to reposition photos for mobile screens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have learned how to reposition by `<style>@media screen and (max-width:800px)` but I dont know how to reposition photos.

On a wide computer screen, I have a group of photos on the right side but on a mobile screen, I want the photos to be at the top.

I also have created a page for mobile screens and maybe I could redirect mobile users to that page but I don't know how to do that.

I don't want the computer screen pages viewed by mobile devices and the mobile screen pages viewed by computers.

My style of CSS is not in accordance with the protocol, however, I find my style much easier to follow and easier to correct mistakes.

This is the coding for the background and one photo for a widescreen. When the screen is narrowed the background repositions the way I want but the photo remains in the original place and is too small.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css"> .images { position: absolute; height: 77%; width: 39%; right: 2.5%; bottom: 6.8%; top: 16%; background-color: #98FF98; } </style>
    <div class="images"></div>  <!--If this line is deleted the background does not appear-->
<style>@media screen and (max-width:800px) { .images { position: absolute; height: 47%; width: 96%; left: 2%; top: 16%; background-color: #98FF98; } }</style>  <!--This line works good when screen is narrowed-->
    <div class="images"></div>  <!--This line does nothing and doesnt need to be there-->

<style type="text/css"> .pha { position: absolute; width: 6%; right: 8.2%; top: 18.5%; } </style>
    <div class="pha"><img alt="Photo" src = "/img/soda.jpg" style="width:160%;" ></div>
<style>@media screen and (max-width:800px) { .pha { position: absolute; width: 6%; left: 7.2%; top: 17%; } }</style> <!--All this line does is deletes the photo when the screen is narrowed-->
    <div class="pha"><img alt="Photo" src = "/img/soda.jpg" style="width:285%;" ></div> <!--This line does not reposition the photo when the screen is narrowed-->

</body>
</html>
```

This is the coding for one photo for a narrow screen. Which is how I want the coding above to look like when the screen is narrowed.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css"> .images { position: absolute; height: 77%; width: 39%; right: 2.5%; bottom: 6.8%; top: 16%; background-color: #98FF98; } </style>
    <div class="images"></div>
<style type="text/css"> .phb { position: absolute; width: 6%; left: 7.2%; top: 17%; } </style>
    <div class="phb"><img alt="Photo" src = "/img/soda.jpg" style="width:285%;" ></div>

</body>
</html>
```

It would be OK to reposition the photo with Javascript if CSS wont fix the problem.

Can anybody help?

UPDATE

Thanks for your input Garth Baker. This is one of many variations I've tried and nothing works so I need your version of where the coding should be placed.

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .only-desktop{
    display:none;
  }
    .phb{
      position: absolute;
        width: 6%;
          left: 7.2%;
            top: 17%;
              }
              {
img alt="Photo"
  src = "/img/soda.jpg"
    style="width:285%;" 
}}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .only-mobile{
    display:none;
  }
   .pha{
    position: absolute;
      width: 6%;
        right: 8.2%;
          top: 18.5%;
            }
            {
img alt="Photo"
  src = "/img/soda.jpg"
    style="width:160%;"
}}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you pls accept an answer... I helped you but you don't want to give me the credit for helping you...

Answer (score 1):

Use this. It will allow you two dynamically adjust your content based on whether or not your screen is below 1023px or above 1024px. The class will do as it says. Only display on desktop. or only display on mobile. wherever you add the classes they will work. :)

You really shouldn't use inline styles. But anyways. Just wrap in the style tags. Press F12 and you will get your developer console that will allow you to view the mobile version.

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .only-desktop{
    display:none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .only-mobile{
    display:none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank Garth Baker but where do I put that coding?

Comment: I just noticed your words "wherever you add the classes they will work"

Comment: yeah so you can make a div for your desktop screens and also for your mobile screens. and build them separately however you want to :)

Comment: Because the class that's hiding the elements only works on a certain width. so that's how it adjusts to show and hide.

Comment: Sorry I posted that comment too soon. I placed that coding at the top of the page & it didn't work.

Comment: When I posted the last comment I noticed your 2 other comments. I'll play with that tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please amend the coding that I submitted to coordinate your media screen coding? I cant get it to work.

Comment: I like constructive criticism but saying I really shouldn't use inline styles, without a reason is not constructive. I prefer inline because it is much easier to follow, detect errors, delete, copy & paste one line.

Comment: I'll amend my question to illustrate what I've tried with your coding.

Comment: I need your advice on how to reposition the "photo". My project is at a standstill. I know how to reposition & resize the background.

Comment: I'd check out position relative. :)

Comment: I found this. It looks like it will help you. https://dzone.com/articles/css-position-relative-vs-position-absolute

Comment: I found that position: absolute works best. I have tried relative but I'll read the link you provided later. I think I've found the solution. Thanks for your input.

Comment: It all depends what functionality you are looking for specifically. Just read up on the differences of relative positioning and absolute :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:-

```
<style type="text/css"> .images { position: absolute; height: 77%; width: 39%; right: 2.5%; bottom: 6.8%; top: 16%; background-color: #98FF98; }</style>
    <div class="images"></div>
<style>@media screen and (max-width:800px) { .images { position: absolute; height: 47%; width: 96%; left: 2%; top: 16%; background-color: #98FF98; } }</style>

<style type="text/css"> .pha { position: absolute; width: 10%; right: 8.2%; top: 18.5%; } </style>
<style>@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { .pha { position: absolute; width: 20%; left: 7.2%; top: 17%; } } </style>
    <div class="pha"><img alt="Photo" src = "/img/soda.jpg" style="width:100%;" ></div>
```

Comment: I will expand on it tomorrow to see if everything else works.

Comment: Everything works good now. If anybody wants to use that coding it's just a matter of changing the percentages to get the right position on the page, and change the photo name and css name.